# Compute Video Size based on Manifest properties and duration

Tags: video, manifest, mp4, http-live-streaming

My question is how can I compute programmatically a video size based on the information that I have from manifest.

I know these:

**Codecs** = mp4a.40.2,avc1.77.30 
**Resolution** = 424x240 
**Frame rate** = 25 / second 
**duration** = 100 seconds // it can change per video

Is there any formula that I can apply so that I can get approximately the video size based on what I know?

Comment: You can't compute the encoded stream size based on the information above. What you need to know is the **average bitrate**, and duration. When video is encoded (compressed), the resolution and frame rate don't determine the total number of bits in the stream.

Comment: I only have the bandwidth.. Could that help? But could you tell me the formula with the average bitrate I might manage to do something..

Comment: The formula is simple: `size_in_bits = average_bitrate*duration`, If you want size in bytes, divide `size_in_bits` by 8. The bandwidth is the upper bound for the bitrate (if the bitrate is higher than the bandwidth, the video transmission is going to fail).

Comment: @Rotem I just Implement what you told me and it worked perfect! If you want post it as an answer to mark it as correct.